# How do I see the contract log events in Ethereum?

Tags: bitcoin, blockchain, ethereum, crowdsourcing, solidity

I finished the https://www.ethereum.org/crowdsale tutorial in Ethereum and intentionally left the crowdsale having failed its funding goal (sample code at the start of the page). I fired the "safeWithdrawal" function from within Ethereum-Wallet and it adds the transaction on to the blockchain. But at this point I do not know how to listen to the response. The ether I sent was not returned.

1. I would like the ether to be returned.
2. I would like to know how to listen to the event that should have fired. Or any feedback mechanism to know that the why / how the event fired.

Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2lsVo.png

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the Ethereum-Wallet has no debugger built-in for smart contracts.

I suggest, you code up your example using the [**browser-solidity**](https://ethereum.github.io/browser-solidity/). It allows you not only to code and test the deployment but got most recently a debugger built in. Click the little bug.

[image: screenshot debugger tab]

The debugger used in browser solidity is [remix](https://github.com/ethereum/remix) which is both a javascript IDE but also a library which can be attached to your own javascript projects. It is possible that future releases of Ethereum-Wallet will also include remix, this would simplify your task pretty much.

But for now, the mentioned browser tool seems like perfectly suited for your needs.